# Snapshot listener returning empty snapshot when I open the fragment again

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment in an activity that uses Firestore snapshot listener. When I first start the fragment, it works fine. But then if I navigate to another fragment and return, I get an empty snapshot. How do I get it to fetch the snapshot properly again?

Here is the query with the listener registration:

```
private void setupRecyclerView() {
    if (mealplanRecycler == null) {
        mealplanRecycler = mealplanView.findViewById(R.id.mealplan_recycler);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mealplanContext);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mealplanRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mealplanRecycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    }
    getMealplans();
}

private void getMealplans() {
        String userId = (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("userId")) ? bundle.getString("userId") : "";
        Query mealplanQuery = firebaseFirestore.collection("Meal_Plans").whereEqualTo("userId", userId).orderBy("timeOfCreation", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
        registration = mealplanQuery.addSnapshotListener((value, error) -> {
            toolbarProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mealplanArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (error == null && value != null) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : value) {
                    Mealplan mealplan = document.toObject(Mealplan.class);
                    Mealplan updatedmealplan = updateTime(mealplan);
                    mealplanArrayList.add(updatedmealplan);
                    if (mealplanArrayList.size() > 0) {
                        tvAddMealplan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        ivAddmealplan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                if (mealPlanAdapter != null) {
                    mealPlanAdapter.setItems(mealplanArrayList);
                    mealPlanAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    String planId = (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("planId")) ? bundle.getString("planId") : "none";
                    mealPlanAdapter = new MealPlanAdapter(mealplanContext, mealplanArrayList, planId);
                    mealplanRecycler.setAdapter(mealPlanAdapter);
                }
                mealPlanAdapter.setEditMealplanListener(this::onButtonPressed);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "error is not null: " + Objects.requireNonNull(error).getLocalizedMessage());
                toolbarProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tvAddMealplan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
```

And this is how I am creating the fragment in Main Activity:

```
MealplanFragment fragment = new MealplanFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right).replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: In which function does the query with the listener registration exist?

Comment: I override onCreateView() --> then setupRecycler() --> and then queryData()

Answer (score 0):

A fragment's *onCreateView* is called only once when the fragment's view is being created. From then on it will be called again only if the view is destroyed and needs to be recreated. It is what function onCreate is for an Activity.

So, when you switch between fragments it is not called.
The solution is to place the listener registration code in a function that will be called when switching fragments.

You can try [onHiddenChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onHiddenChanged(boolean)) function:

```
@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
    if (hidden) {    
    
    } 
    else {

    }
}
```

or

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
    
    } else {
     
    }
}
```

The above are deprecated in API level 28. So, you can also try [setMenuVisibility](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#setMenuVisibility(boolean)):

```
 @Override
 public void setMenuVisibility(boolean isvisible) {
    super.setMenuVisibility(isvisible);
    if (isvisible){
        Log.d("Viewpager", "fragment is visible ");
    }else {
        Log.d("Viewpager", "fragment is not visible ");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that before and again after your comment. I put the recyclerview creation as part of the onCreateView and the listener registration in onStart/onResume. It doesn't help. I end up with the same problem where the snapshot is empty. I updated the code above to show the functions.

Comment: I edited my answer to suggest that you also try onHiddenChanged function, which is called everytime the visibility of a fragment is changed.

Comment: Unfortunately, the min API I am supporting is level 28 and onHiddenChanged was deprecated in that level. I tried it out just to see and that function isn't even overriden.

Comment: I suggest that you also try setMenuVisibility. It is also deprecated in api level 28, but in other threads it appeared as the only solution after onHiddenChanged was deprecated.

Comment: Also, if you are using a tab/button or a gesture to change fragments, maybe you can hook your code with these actions.